# TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases module

Tags: python, inheritance, import, module

I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/repos/prodigy/Sweeper/envsweeper/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/loader.py", line 414, in loadTestsFromName
    addr.filename, addr.module)
  File "/Users/user/repos/dr/Sweeper/envsweeper/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/importer.py", line 47, in importFromPath
    return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
  File "/Users/user/repos/prodigy/Sweeper/envsweeper/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/importer.py", line 94, in importFromDir
    mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
  File "/Users/user/repos/dr/Sweeper/test.py", line 5, in <module>
    from SomethingSubclass import SomethingSubclass
      File "/Users/user/repos/dr/Something/SomethingSubclass.py", line 18, in <module>
    class SomethingSubclass(SomethingBaseclass):

TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

This is the code in the `Base` class:

```
import os
import sys
import inspect
from settings import picklePass, masterMap
from decimal import Decimal
CURRENTDIR = os.path.dirname(
    os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))
parentdir = os.path.dirname(CURRENTDIR)
sys.path.insert(0, parentdir)
from libs.pickler.pickler import Pickler
import logging


class BaseClass(object):

    def __init__(self, address, fee, msg_body):
        self.address = address
        self.fee = (fee)
        self.msg_body = msg_body
```

This would be the code in the `SubClass` that is throwing the error, filename: `SubClass.py`:

```
import os
import sys
import inspect
import Sweeper
CURRENTDIR = os.path.dirname(
    os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))
parentdir = os.path.dirname(CURRENTDIR)
sys.path.insert(0, parentdir)
from libs.deterministic import electrum_privkey
from libs.transaction import sign, mksend
import logging
sys.path.insert(0, CURRENTDIR)


class SubClass(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, address, fee, msg_body):
        BaseClass.__init__(self, address, fee, msg_body)
```

And this is how the subclass is instantiated:

```
....           
module = __import__('SubClass')
class_ = getattr(module, 'SubClass')
```

Any clues on what might be wrong?

Comment: Where does the `SomethingSubClass.py` file come from in your traceback? Why do you use `class SomethingSubclass.py(...)`, that's not valid Python code.  I don't see any metaclasses in your posted code either. What is the *full traceback* of the error?

Comment: There are a whole load of other questions about the posted code. Why all the mucking with `sys.path`? Why use module names that match the class names, Python is not java and modules do not have to use the same name as a class contained theirin; the convention is to use lower_case_with_underscores for module names (minimising underscores here possible).

Comment: Then there is the use of `__import__` rather than straight importing; you may have a usecase for this but it is surely not relevant to the problem at hand; can you produce a [mcve] without all the extras here?

Comment: OK, fair questions. I'll try to answer them in the same sequence:

1) I didnt' use class SomethingSubclass.py(...), I'm not sure where you got this.
2)I need to change the sys path to access libs in other directories and import them:
3)You are absolutely right about the module names, I will change this, thank you :).
4)I'm using __import__ because of precisely that uses case you mentioned, I need to import different subclasses depending on a parameter. I Hardcoded this in particular for the example.

Comment: For #1, look closely at the traceback you posted.

Comment: Sorry! Autocomplete error, it didn't actually come out. I'll post the full traceback.

Comment: @MartijnPieters changing the filenames to what's stipulated by python convention fixed it. It was a weird problem. 

THANK YOU SO MUCH.

You should post it as an Answer.

Comment: That... doesn't make much sense. I can post that, but it won't help future visitors figure out what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

```
from module'name import class'name
```

Don't use

```
import class'name
```

if your module and class have the same name.
It will confuse the different names.